# matplotlib: add special math symbol to xticklabels

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, symbols, superscript

I am following the example code [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) to produce a bar chart. I just want to add a superscript *\textdagger*(†) to the last group name "G5". Here is what I tried (check the line `ax.set_xticklabels`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, color='r', yerr=men_std)

women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y', yerr=women_std)

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width)
ax.set_xticklabels(('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5\textsuperscript{\textdagger}'))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

But the output is totally messed up.
[image]

How can I get a proper superscript † for "G5" then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many tex commands can be used within matplotlib without the need to use tex itself; this is called MathText. Like tex commands, you would enclose MathText command with two dollar signs.

```
'G5$^\dagger$'
```

Now, even if you use tex (`plt.rc('text', usetex = True)`) the command stays the same:

```
'G5$^\dagger$'
```